# request qs key value encoded, How to disable encode string?

Tags: node.js, request

```
var Request = require("request")

var options = {
    url: option.apiUrl,
    qs: {
      apiKey: "T%2BLkADWTX0OzgMMDmEPHffxQNYcgNMyfYJcXyR0cl0%2BNe8w0g%3D%3D", 
    }
    json: true
}



function handleResponse (error, response, body) {


    console.log(response) //apiKey is changed to T%252BLkADWTX0OzgMMDmEPHffxQNYcgNMyfYJcXyR0cl0%252BNe8w0g%253D%253D



}

Request(options, handleResponse);
```

Hi,

the apiKey is changed to wrong Key.

What option should I add for disable string encode on request qs?

or What is alternative way to get Json API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its because your api key is uri encoded with encodeURIComponent() as a query string , so specials char like %3D become 25%3D when the request is encoded again, if you use decodeURIComponent you can have the right apiKey that will be encoded properly

```
   var string = "T%2BLkADWTX0OzgMMDmEPHffxQNYcgNMyfYJcXyR0cl0%2BNe8w0g%3D%3D"
   decodeURIComponent(string) // "T+LkADWTX0OzgMMDmEPHffxQNYcgNMyfYJcXyR0cl0+Ne8w0g=="
```

PS: you shouldnt share API keys on SO